# 整数フィールドに対する部分一致検索

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-server, oracle

整数フィールド（値の範囲は0～99）に対して、それを文字列とみなして部分一致で検索するSELECT文を書きたいです。
例えば "7" を指定すれば、"17" とか "73" とかがヒットします。
ここで欲しいSQL文は、SQLServerでもOracleでもPostgreSQLでも実行可能なものです。
何か方法はあるでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

フィールドをキャストすることで部分一致検索をすることができます。

```
SELECT * FROM テーブル WHERE CAST(整数フィールド AS TEXT) LIKE '%7%';
```

Comment: SQL ServerとOracleは`TEXT`型ではなく、`VARCHAR(VARCHAR2)`型ですよね？

Comment: そうですね。PostgreSQLで確認したまま載せてしまいました...

Comment: 整数の範囲が決まっているのならば、 `CHAR(2)` が割と広く使える文字列型なのではないのかな、と思っています。